# Omitting .html extension from url path using NextJS static website hosting on AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3, next.js

I am hosting a NextJS app by exporting (`next export`) the static bundle to S3. I am able to access the page from the S3 bucket endpoint. For example, `https://my-website.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/user/v1/login.html`.

However, I am having problem trying to access the page by omitting the .html extension from the URL path. For example, `https://my-website.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/user/v1/login` should produce the same behaviour as the `/user/v1/login.html`.

S3 is returning `403 Access Denied` error instead of returning the html page. I have tried several ways such as configuring `trailingSlash: true` as well as configuring a `rewrite()` in `next.config.js` but I still can't achieve the intended behaviour.

I have also read up solution in removing the .html from the html files but I am building the website using CodeBuild and this solution
doesn't really scales well as I have to manually rename the files generated from `next export`.

Is there any other ways for me to configure in NextJS or S3 so that I can omit the .html extension in the URL path?

**Update:**

I was able to achieve the above intended behaviour using CloudFront with S3 website endpoint as a custom origin.

However, I am facing with another issue whereby the path gets a trailing slash appended to the path uri when there are query string parameters.

For example, https://abcdefgh.cloudfront.net/dev/v1/login?foo=bar will be changed to https://abcdefgh.cloudfront.net/dev/v1/login/?foo=bar in the browser url path. How can I stop CloudFront from appending the slash at the end of the url path?

Comment: could you detail how you proceeded with CloudFront

Answer (score 0):

To get all of

- http://foo/bar
- http://foo/bar/index.html
- http://foo/bar.html
- http://foo/bar/

assuming a exported file from next as:

`bar/index.html`

you need to use `aws cp` to

- copy everything up in one glob, this ups all your css/img/js and the html as is and gives you `http://foo/bar/index.html`
- step through all "index.html" (use `find . -name "index.html"),` aws cp`it up with`s//index.html//`. this gives you` http://foo/bar`
- step through all "index.html" (use `find . -name "index.html"),` aws cp`it up with`s//index.html/.html/`. this gives you` http://foo/bar.html`

you'll only get `http://foo/bar/` if you either:

- write a cloudfront function to intercept and loading `bar/index.html` regardless of the trailingslash or not in the request.
- join your cloudfront to your s3 bucket via the s3 website url instead of the s3 rest endpoint.

both  those options result in extra costs.

Answer (score 0):

Stripping `.html` is a wrong approach. And Next.js approach forsing you to buy some paid solutions is also wrong ))

With Apache `mod_rewrite` you could:

```
<Directory "${webDir}">
  Require all granted
  LogLevel rewrite:trace8
  RewriteEngine On
  # Find .html file if one exists.
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}\.html -f
  RewriteRule ^ %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html [L]
</Directory>
```

But in S3 bucket you don't have conditional logic of checking of file existence.

Instead you generate Next.js static site with `index.html` trick in `next.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    trailingSlash: true
}
```

and tell **Default Root Object: index.html**, so logical paths, like `/login`, will be resolved into directory with default listing handler, like `/login/index.html`. `trailingSlash` controls such behavior.